# Why does NETWORK SERVICE own my RAID?

Tags: raid, windows-server-essentials

I inherited a Windows Server Essentials 2016 machine that's set up with a C system drive and a D RAID. The problem is the D drive, on which everything works as expected below the top level. At the top level, though, I'm quite limited in what I can do. Notably, despite being Administrator, I can't change any permissions. I can see that the owner is NETWORK SERVICE.

I should add that this is my first time working with a RAID.

My questions are:

1. Why is NETWORK SERVICE the owner? What should the owner be?
2. What happens if I change the owner of a RAID?

Comment: We aren't able to tell you why the file system is permissioned the way it is.